# When does a self-identifier become accessible in F#?

Tags: f#

When is object construction finished and how finished does it need to be before properties are accessed via `self`?

The following code shows a simple reactive UI. `MutableIntViewer` is intended to print the initial value of `x` and any changes. Is it guaranteed to work?

```
type IntViewer() =
    member _.Content with set (v:int) = printf "%i" v

type Mutable<'a when 'a:equality>(init:'a) =
    let mutable value = init
    let e = Event<'a>()
    member _.Bind(f:'a->unit) =
        f value
        e.Publish.Add f
    member _.Value 
        with get() = value
        and set v =
            value <- v
            e.Trigger v

type MutableIntViewer(x:Mutable<int>) as self =
    inherit IntViewer() 
    do  x.Bind self.set_Content
```

**Why it should succeed:** `self.set_Content` is just `base.set_Content` which is already there.

**Why it should fail:** `self` does not exist as an `MutableIntViewer` at the point at which `do  x.Bind self.SetContent` is called, since the `MutableIntViewer` is still being constructed.

When we use this pattern it almost always works, but we have had an isolated case of an exception `...an object or value being accessed recursively before it was fully initialized.`.

Note that using `base` here instead of `self` gives the error `...'base' is being used. This is only allowed in the direct implementation of members since they could escape their object scope.`.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve with this?  This seems extraordinary effort to do something in an imperative/mutable way when perhaps a more idiomatic e.g. functional way exists.  perhaps if you provide  a bit more context what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @KoenigLear What is the effort? The Mutable type is just a simplified reactive API. You can use for example a Gjallarhorn Mutable or Signal in its place. In good reactive code there will be mutables at the base, which can be manually changed, and maps of those, which respond to these changes. The intent is to use for reactive UI. In almost any UI framework there is a `View` type. The code above allows you to create something you can use as a `View` (by inheriting from it), and which initializes/updates reactively in response to some signal.

Comment: According to [this](https://sharplab.io/#v2:DYLgZgzgNAJiDUAfALgTwA4FMAEBJAdsgGoCWmA7pgE4AUAlNgLwCwAUNh9gLaZcBG1bAH0AdAGEA9oUyFs5EsgAW2CJmTYaANxAlCDRtnRVdyMNgBEAUhLnsmtmzRZsAWQCuyAIZ9gmADwA5J5yijLYQSCYAI5unsAKqAB8NLoKIEH6bJzYvupcHt6+dnFuOAapyFmcudhl2ACimjLIgZ7JdFUcPPyCogBCujA0YOmeALSJbvgKmezZnGaaJZid85giAApuPiQQiiIAgjAw2GCr3QJUwiJEy9ir2fJK2ADmavRMxcClD5ye+CdVOpNExfvMvqVsH4xnYwWsRAAVYwvN5XeysRwYHDuLw+TAEYhkSi0AAeIBxhX8JkSDE8EBUmGAZhYcw4ulCxnUBNIFGoH1WMAkHBJIgGAIZTJEQKEkmkhCAA==) the constructor completes before the self-reference is taken.

Comment: @CharlesRoddie    Apologies, I didn't know the context. I expected a reactive UI to
   be a function Event->State->State which can be composed with many such functions such as Elmish where there's no need for mutables.   
Apparently, what you describe is the approach needed for Windows Forms.